Error "The macro may not be available in this service or all macros may be disabled." from C# code that executes a VBA macro
I've written a C# program that uses Excel Interop libraries to open a file and execute a macro.
I've been using this program for quite some time on a server running Windows 2016 and Excel 2016.
Now I'm updating the server to Windows 2019 and Excel 2021.
On this new environment, when I run the same program with the same Excel file, I get the error:

The macro may not be available in this service or all macros may be disabled.

I've enabled all macros on both environments following the same steps:

In Microsoft Excel, click File > Options > General

Disable Show the Start screen when this application starts


In Microsoft Excel, click File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings…

Click ActiveX Settings
Select Safe mode
Select Enable all control without restrictions and without prompting (not recommended; potentially dangerous controls can run)
Click Macro Settings
Select Enable all macros (not reccomanded; potentially dangerous controls can run)
Click Protected View and clear all the options
Click Privacy options
Clear all options under Privacy options
Clear the Warn before printing option under Document specific settings


Close Microsoft Office applications
Disable User Account Control (UAC) by using Control Panel > Users on your computer
Add the administrator user from step 7 to Distributed COM users group:

Type lusrmgr.msc from the Run window
Click Groups
Right-click Distributed COM Users group
Select Properties
Click Add and add the administrator user from step 7
Click OK


Add the administrator user for the Microsoft Office applications:

Type mmc -32 in the Run window
Click File > Add Remove Snap-in > Component Services
Click Add
Click OK
Navigate to Console Root > Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM
Config
Right-click on Microsoft Excel Application and select Properties
Click the Identity tab
Select This user, click Browse and search for the Administrator user who launches the
Document Transformation Service. Enter the credentials for the Administrator user
Click the Location tab
Select Run application on this computer




Try to do the following:

Check Unblock checkbox in macro file properties dialog.
Add folder with macro to Excel trusted locations


I already tried both actions without success.
